# Customizing a jquery script. Accordion style vertical menu for magento

Tags: jquery, magento, menu, jquery-ui-accordion

I found this jquery script online and need to customize it a little. What it does is makes the vertical menu in magento have an accordion effect. It only does so for the first category though and doesn't allow you to visit it. I want to keep that but also allow lower categories to be opened in the same style but have them go to the proper page when clicked as well. I hope that made sense!

Here is the script:

```
//
// this script was written by Ben Frain - more info at http://www.benfrain.com
// 
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery('ul#vertnav > li > ul')
    .click(function(e){
      e.stopPropagation();
    })
    .hide();



//this section below prevents the first level links being followed. 
  jQuery('ul#vertnav > li').click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
});

  jQuery('ul#vertnav > li, ul#vertnav > li > ul > li').click(function(){
    var selfClick = jQuery(this).find('ul:first').is(':visible');
    if(!selfClick) {
      jQuery(this)
        .parent()
        .find('> li ul:visible')
        .slideToggle();

    }

    jQuery(this)
      .find('ul:first')
      .stop(true, true)
      .slideToggle();

  });

  //this section make the nereast ul section to the link show
  var url = window.location.toString() // this will return http://mydomain.com/pagename.html?query=xxxxxx


  // this bit adds a class to the active section for CSS 
  jQuery('ul#vertnav > li a').each(function(){
      var myHref= jQuery(this).attr('href');
      if( url.match( myHref)) {
           jQuery(this).addClass('activeClassNameForCSSHighlight')
            jQuery(this).closest('ul').show();
      }
});

});
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Please create a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) for us to work with.

Comment: a js fiddle with magento seems difficult.

Comment: try this link [Vertical Accordion Menu](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/4_-_themes_and_template_customization/navigation/magento_vertical_accordion_menu_using_scriptaculous)

Answer (score 1):

replace

```
jQuery('ul#vertnav > li > ul')
```

by

```
jQuery('ul#vertnav').find('li > ul')
```

where it occurs.

and it should work. check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rnFkg/2/)

**EDIT :** In my fiddle, I did modify a bit the logic for hiding "other" menus when one is clicked, and used more variables instead of selectors (for performance reasons).

Comment: Thanks for trying to help but now the second menu does not open at all.

Comment: Ok, now when I click on a category within the root it closes the accordion. Help is appreciated though!

Comment: corrected again, a nasty little bug got in :) [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rnFkg/3/)

Comment: Now the child categories are shown when I click on a root category but the links do not work and they don't show their child categories either. Do you need to see the phtml file that calls the vertical navigation bar?

Comment: I don't think I need the phtml. I did [update my fiddle again](http://jsfiddle.net/rnFkg/4/). However, I don't understand what you mean by "links should show their child categories". If they are links, how can they have children??

Comment: ho! I think I understand how it's is supposed to work. A "link" only load the right "column", but the menu (categories) isn't reloaded. And even if it's a full page reload (which magento is s*** to do), the menu initialize (open) on the active category. If so, something is missing in the code you provided, as links are "blocked", but nothing is added to handle a link click.

Comment: Alright, I have no idea how to code jquery do you have any ideas how I could about this?

Comment: I'm still not sure what you want to do :/ try to uncomment/comment `jQuery(this).closest('ul').show();` in your page (based on my latest fiddle, 2 comments ago). And tell me what's wrong. And be strong ;)